# undefined song when I run the play command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to build a music discord bot with `yt-search` but it gives me `undefined` whenever I play the song and it joins the voice channel without playing the song. I'm trying to use `yt-search` to find the video I want or only the URL then pass it to `ytdl` to run it with the URL given from `yt-search` but I think I'm wrong in some points. I don't know where, could you please fix my code ?

Image to show the problem:

[image]

My code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { prefix, token } = require("./config.json");
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const yts = require("yt-search");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const queue = new Map();

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
});

client.once("reconnecting", () => {
  console.log("Reconnecting!");
});

client.once("disconnect", () => {
  console.log("Disconnect!");
});

client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
    execute(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}skip`)) {
    skip(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
    stop(message, serverQueue);
    return;
  } else {
    message.channel.send("You need to enter a valid command!");
  }
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
  const args = message.content.split(" ");

  const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
  if (!voiceChannel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
    );
  const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
  if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
    return message.channel.send(
      "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
    );
  }
  const r = await yts(args[1,2]);
  const video = r.videos.slice( 0, 1 );
  console.log(video);
  const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(video.url);
  const song = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
   };

  if (!serverQueue) {
    const queueContruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
      voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      volume: 5,
      playing: true
    };

    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

    queueContruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
      var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      queueContruct.connection = connection;
      play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      return message.channel.send(err);
    }
  } else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
  }
}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could skip!");
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
    
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could stop!");
    
  serverQueue.songs = [];
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
  if (!song) {
    serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return;
  }

  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
    .play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on("finish", () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
  serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
}

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors. I'm not sure what you think `args[1,2]` is but it's the same as `args[2]` which is the third item of the `args` array. By reading your code, I think you want to use a string here, the search term. By removing the first item (the command) from the `args` array and joining the rest of them, you will receive a string you can use as keywords. Check out the example below:

```js
const message = { content: '!play some music I want'}
const args = message.content.split(' ')

console.log({ args })
// => ["!play", "some", "music", "I", "want"]
console.log({ 'args[1, 2]': args[1, 2] })
// => "music"
console.log({ 'search': args.slice(1).join(' ') })
// => "some music I want"
```

The other error is that `await yts(query)` returns an array of results and when you define the `video` variable you use `r.videos.slice(0, 1)`. The `.slice()` method returns a new array with the first item of `r.videos`.

As the `video` variable is an array, `video.url` is undefined. You could fix it by using the first item instead as it will have a `url` property. You should also check if there are any search results.

Check out the updated code below:

```js
async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
  const args = message.content.split(' ');

  const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
  if (!voiceChannel)
    return message.channel.send(
      'You need to be in a voice channel to play music!',
    );
  const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
  if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
    return message.channel.send(
      'I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!',
    );
  }
  const query = args.slice(1).join(' ');
  const results = await yts(query);

  if (!results.videos.length)
    return message.channel.send(`No results for \`${query}\``);

  const firstVideo = results.videos[0];
  const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(firstVideo.url);
  const song = {
    title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
    url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
  };
  console.log(song);

  if (!serverQueue) {
    // ...
    // ...
```